# Walmart inventory update not working facing 400

Tags: php, xml, curl, walmart-api

I'm trying to update walmart inventory using curl api but facing issue with 400 error response code.

Here is my sample code : I followed walmart [doc](https://developer.walmart.com/#/apicenter/marketPlace/v2#updateInventoryForAnItem), visited error code related walmart documents and found that they are asking to submit ticket so no solution found publicly.

```
$URL = "https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v2/inventory?sku=xxxxx";
$RequestMethod = 'PUT';
$Timestamp = round(microtime(true) * 1000); //Current system timestamp
$WalmartConsumerID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";  

$Signature = _GetWalmartAuthSignature($URL, $RequestMethod, $Timestamp); 



$headers = array();
   $headers[] = "Accept: application/xml";
   $headers[] = "Content-type: application/xml";
   $headers[] = "WM_SVC.NAME: Walmart Marketplace";
   $headers[] = "WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID: ".mt_rand();
   $headers[] = "WM_SEC.TIMESTAMP: ".$Timestamp;
   $headers[] = "WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE: ".$Signature;
   $headers[] = "WM_CONSUMER.ID: ".$WalmartConsumerID;
   $headers[] = "WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE: 0f3e4dd4-0514-4346-b39d-af0e00ea";




 $data = file_get_contents('inventory.xml');
   $ch = curl_init($URL);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
   $response = curl_exec($ch);
   echo $erroe = curl_error($ch);
   echo $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Response  : 400

This is what exactly explained in walmart api doc.

P.S: Get inventory, get order and update price working fine with same key and signature.
    Here is my xml data

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <inventory xmlns:ns2="http://walmart.com/">
    <sku>Cxxxx2</sku>
    <quantity>
    <unit>EACH</unit>
    <amount>7</amount>
    </quantity>
    <fulfillmentLagTime>1</fulfillmentLagTime>
    </inventory>
```

Comment: Have you double checked that your `$data`-variable contains the correct fields? It's hard for us to help you debug this since we don't know what data you're posting.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i updated question with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are other APIs working correctly? The reason I ask is because I see that in the sample code for _GetWalmartAuthSignature, you are not passing consumer id and private key, which is needed for generating the signature.

Also, can you post the entire error you are getting?

They also have a new token based authentication method which is a lot simpler.

https://developer.walmart.com/#/apicenter/marketPlace/latest#apiAuthentication

Also, check if GET inventory is working fine or not for the same sku

---UPDATE ----

Looks like the request payload is missing the

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

--- UPDATE ---

Your xml was not conforming to the xsd
Use this (removing :ns2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inventory xmlns="http://walmart.com/">
<sku>Cxxxx2</sku>
<quantity>
<unit>EACH</unit>
<amount>7</amount>
</quantity>
<fulfillmentLagTime>1</fulfillmentLagTime>
</inventory>
```

Comment: yes other api working fine and i pass consumer id and private key inside GetWalmartAuthSignature() function.
getting 400 HTTP_CODE as response

Comment: What is the error you are getting (entire error response)? Along with status code, they also provide error details in the response

Comment: The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request    code : 400

Comment: There should be some error in the response. Try invoking the same call using a rest client like Postman or something similar and see if that works

Comment: Here id postman response  : 

<ns2:code>INVALID_REQUEST_CONTENT.GMP_INVENTORY_API</ns2:code>
        <ns2:description>com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; unexpected element (uri:&quot;&quot;, local:&quot;inventory&quot;). Expected elements are &lt;{http://walmart.com/}inventory&gt;</ns2:description>
<ns2:info>Request content is invalid.</ns2:info>

Comment: I believe, your xml is missing <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> at the top of the payload. Looks like their sample payload is wrong. If that works, mark this as the correct answer